# Command line tool to export/import .fdf (PDF annotations)

Tags: pdf

I'm looking for a tool that I can run from CMD to **export or import the .fdf** annotations file giving it the path of the .pdf file through CMD.

***Preferences:***
Price: Any
Openness: Open Source (preferable)
OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

[**PDFtk Server**](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) should do what you want to do.

Here are the relevant parts from [their Manual](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-generate-fdf):

> ### `generate_fdf`
>
> Reads a single input PDF file and generates an FDF file suitable for
>   fill_form. It saves this FDF file using the output filename. If no
>   output filename is give, it outputs the FDF to stdout. Does not create
>   a new PDF.
>
> ### `fill_form < FDF data filename | XFDF data filename | - | PROMPT >`
>
> Fills the single input PDF’s form fields with the data from an FDF
>   file, XFDF file or stdin. Enter the data filename after fill_form, or
>   use - to pass the data via stdin, like so:
>
> pdftk form.pdf fill_form data.fdf output form.filled.pdf
>
> If the input FDF file includes Rich Text formatted data in addition to
>   plain text, then the RichText data is packed into the form fields as
>   well as the plain text. Pdftk also sets a flag that cues
>   Reader/Acrobat to generate new field appearances based on the Rich
>   Text data. So when the user opens the PDF, the viewer will create the
>   Rich Text fields on the spot. If the user’s PDF viewer does not
>   support Rich Text, then the user will see the plain text data instead.
>   If you flatten this form before Acrobat has a chance to create (and
>   save) new field appearances, then the plain text field data is what
>   you’ll see in the flattened PDF.

Answer (score 1):

In case you can't find a CLI, making your own CLI is often trivial. Just need to find an SDK that can import/export FDF, and then "wrap". The company I work for offers such an SDK, though requires licensing. Using our SDK you could create a native binary CLI, or a Java/C#/Python one, and then call that CLI anyway you like.

[www.pdftron.com](http://www.pdftron.com)